# Is there a known criterion for a compact complex analytic space to be projective?

Tags: complex-geometry

It is known when a compact complex analytic space $X$ is the analytification of a complex projective variety? If $X$ is a manifold, then Kodaira's embedding theorem and Chow's theorem says that $X$ is the analytification of a complex projective variety if and only if $X$ admits a Kaehler metric whose associated cohomology class lies in the image of the map $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same Kodaira embedding theorem holds as you stated it for proper Kähler analytic spaces (with the usual notion of Kähler metric on an analytic space), and was proved by [Hans Grauert,](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01441136) see Satz 3 in section 3.

Note that in that paper he uses a slightly different definition of Kähler metric, and therefore he needs to assume that $X$ is normal, but with the usual definition this assumption is not needed (and his proof works), see e.g. [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01198581), Theorem 1.1 which is the relative version of the result you want.